# Django: Sorl Thumbnail. Image works first time only

Tags: python, django, image, sorl-thumbnail

I've been using **Sorl thumbnail** in many projects and never had an issue like this one.

- I have configured `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL`
- The first time I enter the page, when thumbnail generates the image for first time, it works well
- The url of the image this first time is like:

  `<img src="/media/cache/a2/ee/a2eefc9888cea70482961f4484e1d046.jpg">`

  This image url works perfectly, and the image is rendered as expected

My issue is when I load the page again, I don't know why but the img url is:

`<img src="/media/ccea/eaef98ca089148ed4.p%00%00/d/r/ciia-iiacnut--uet">`

I don't know why the first time works and then when I reload the page it's like the image url is being parsed or something

- I have in my settings.py: `THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = DEBUG`
- Media/Static are well defined

Django Code in template:

```
{% if object.image %}
    {% thumbnail object.image "300" as im %}
        <img src="{{im.url}}">
    {% endthumbnail %}
{% endif %}
```

Thanks

---

## Edit1

I change some parts on my code, reinstall sorl-thumbnail, stopped the `memchached` process and now the error is:

```
JSONDecodeError at /my/url/

Exception Type: JSONDecodeError
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

The error is in the first line of this 3 lines:

```
{% thumbnail object.image "500" as im %}
    {{im.url }}
{% endthumbnail %}
```

*I'm not using json, this issue is internal of sorl-thumbnail*

It seems the problems come from:

**/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sorl/thumbnail/kvstores/base.py in _get**

```
deserialize_image_file(value)  # Internal sorl-thumbnail call
```

Variables value:
**value:**`u'{"storage": "django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage", "name": "cache/5a/a0/5aa0be82eaf67259f4dee13128372d1e.jpg", "size": [499, 474]}'`

*You can check the url is well formated before calling deserialize-image-file*

Thing's already tried:

- `python manage.py thumbnail clear`
- `python manage.py thumbnail cleanup`
- Empty sorl database tables
- Reinstall `Sorl-thumbnail`
- Stopped `memcached` process and remove `memcached` configuration from settings.py

Comment: kvstore object changes (table thumbnail_kvstore in your db) or problem only while rendering?

Comment: also if it change your `object` define django post_save signal, handler for it and look throughout debug trace where it happens

Comment: There is no issue, at least sorl-thumbnail doesn't return any error. The first time the image is rendered perfect, after that the url changes as you can see above

Comment: Are you using `MediaS3BotoStorage = lambda: S3BotoStorage(location='media')` to specify your S3 storage location?

Comment: I am having the same issue - but the issue is that Sorl loads the right S3 url the first time with the right media prefix. One the second time, it drops the prefix. So its looking for an image that isn't there.